# How do I construct the packets for this UDP protocol?

Tags: python, network-programming, network-protocols

Valve Software's Steam Server Query protocol as documented [here](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_Queries) allows you to query their game servers for various data.  This is a little out of my depth and I'm looking for a little guidance as to what I need to learn.

I'm assuming I'll need [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) and [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html), correct?

I'm comfortable with basic UDP tasks like [these](http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/07/socket-programming-tutorial.html), so I guess my main question is how do I construct my data with struct, as I'm completely unfamiliar with it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question.  Yay.

[SRCDS.py](https://sourceforge.net/projects/srcdspy/) has this implemented already and I figured it out by looking it over.